# How to make verticaltext cellstyle with Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Recently, I met a question:
I need to export an excel(xlsx) with java, which must contain this kind of cell style:

[image]

I made a excel file with this vertical text, and exported as a xml file. Then I found that the style has an attribute named 'VerticalText':

[image]

By experience, I chose Apache POI. But I couldn't find any way to generate the cell style with POI. I could only find rotate method, which could't meet the requirement.

So I read more code of POI, and found that the cellstyles are build from some xsb file, which do not contain vertical text either.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The XML in your picture is Excel 2003 SpreadsheetML. But an `*.xlsx` file is a ZIP archive containing Office Open XML files. In that ZIP archive the `styles.xml` contains:

```
...
<cellXfs count="2">
 ...
 <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0">
  <alignment textRotation="255"/>
 </xf>
</cellXfs>
...
```

There `<alignment textRotation="255"/>` is for vertical text.

This can be set using `apache poi` like so:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class CreateXSSFVerticalText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  cellStyle.setRotation((short)255);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("test");
  cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);


  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("CreateXSSFVerticalText.xlsx");
  workbook.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Since the Office Open XML formats (like `*.xlsx`) are ZIP archives containing XML files it is pretty easy to determine the necessary XML attributes. Simply create a simple `*.xlsx` file having the needed formatting using the `Excel` GUI. Then unzip the `*.xlsx` file and have a look at `xl/styles.xml`.

Comment: I tried setRotation(90) before, but did not meet the requirement.  why is 255? It  is amazing!!

Comment: See my supplement about how to determine the necessary XML attributes.