# POI: how to set text vertical in excel

Tags: java, excel, text, apache-poi

I would like to consult about the POI operation in excel. I'd like to use java to set the text vertical display in excel, but still cannnot find a way to solve it, it should look like the following:

when I type "abc", it should display:

a

b

c

in the cell, which is vertical text in excel

I'm very appreciate someone could give me some hints or suggestion, thank you in advance!

Comment: I found there is a textdirection class, but i don't know how to use it, and there is no text direction related method in the cellstyle method

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053926/how-to-make-verticaltext-cellstyle-with-apache-poi/42054198#42054198

Comment: Thanks Axel, it works now, very helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make verticaltext cellstyle with Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053926/how-to-make-verticaltext-cellstyle-with-apache-poi)